# How can I build a nested tree with CTE from a spaced inner text?

Tags: sql, sql-server, tree, common-table-expression

Given the following table of a data (Imported data from Comma Delimited Components List)

```
[SQL CTE]
;WITH COMPONENTS(ID, TEXT, CHILD) AS 
(
   SELECT 
     ID,TEXT, (CASE WHEN PATINDEX(' %',TEXT)=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
   FROM tblComponents
) 
SELECT * FROM COMPONENTS

[TABLE DATA]
ID  |   TEXT        |   ISCHILD
------------------------------------------------
1   |   PARENT1     |   0
2   |   PARENT2     |   0
3   |     CHILD1    |   1
4   |     CHILD2    |   1
```

The spacing of the data identifies that the above CHILD1, CHILD2 are both children of PARENT2.  AS they have spacing at their beginning and their order assumes that they are children of ID 2.

Is this possible; I've already run a query with `PATINDEX(' %',TEXT)=1` to give me the ISCHILD.

Note: Assuming only Parent->ManyChildren (regardless of how many spaces are in TEXT) and no grandchildren;  I am interested only in the initial relationship.

```
[ORIGINAL DATA]
ID,COMPONENT,
44,"COMPONENT1 contains:",
45,"  CHILD1 ",
46,"  CHILD2   ",
47,"  CHILD3 ",
```

Expected/Needed Output:

```
ID  |   TEXT        |   PARENT_ID
------------------------------------------------
1   |   PARENT1     |   0
2   |   PARENT2     |   0
3   |     CHILD1    |   2
4   |     CHILD2    |   2
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The answer may depend on it...)

Comment: SQL SERVER > 2008 R2

Comment: You say you are using a CTE, can you post the SQL for that please?

Comment: Wouldn't it be wise to have a parentId instead of trusting to the order and spacing?

Comment: As this is imported from a static list csv data.  The inherent trees are calculated based on their position in the CSV through spacing.  (Wise yes, feasible after the fact...no).

Comment: Ah wise and feasible then :) I have already been there done that. It was just not the job of the SQL but the programming language I use.

Comment: How deep does this hierarchy go? Is it just Parent->manyChildren, with no grandchildren?

Comment: at present; I am only going to assume Parent->ManyChildren;

Comment: And when you say "Nested tree" what is that output that you are looking for? Can you give a quick example of what the output recordset would look like given this input?

Comment: Could you past some lines of your csv data? The import could be easier in one go... And please give an example of the expected result.

Comment: If you can use SQL Server 2012 you could use LAG(). Is this an option?

Comment: Does the input parent/child relation have to be "ordered"? Does the children rows have to be directly below the parent row?

Comment: yes all children are ordered by their location in the data and  are children by this and the space in their text field.  LAG, PATINDEX, CTE and ETC Are available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The big problem you are going to run into is that you are encoding information about your data in the ORDER of the records in your table. I can guarantee you that this will only lead to death and destruction.

Thankfully you do have an "ID" that appears to maintain the order of the data outside of the order that the records are written to the filesystem, so that's a step in the right direction. Furthermore you have identified children by looking for leading whitespace. So you are on the right track.

The next step is to determine which Parent the children belong to. You could do something like:

```
SELECT
    id,
    text,
    ischild,
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 id FROM Components WHERE isChild = 0 AND children.id > Components.id   ORDER BY id ASC
    ) AS parent_id

FROM components as children
```

If the hierarchy is deeper than just one level and the only way you can determine that a child is connected to a parent is by the spacing at the front then you could get more creative:

```
SELECT
    id,
    text,
    ischild,
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 id FROM Components
        WHERE 
            children.id > Components.id AND
            (len(Components.text) - len(replace(Components.text,' ',''))) < (len(children.text) - len(replace(children.text, ' ',''))) AND
            Components.isChild = 0
        ORDER BY id ASC
    ) AS parent_id

FROM components as children
```

With this last one we are moving through each record and then looking for the highest parent id that has:

1. an ID that is less than the child record we are looking at
2. has less leading spaces than the child record we are looking at

The recordset from this statement will now have the child's id and the parent's id. If the parent's id is NULL is then we know we are at a root node of the hierarchy.

From here you can build a recursive view to look at the hierarchical path, depth of node, and whatever else you want to squeeze out of a hierarchy:

```
WITH recursiveCTE
AS
(
    SELECT 
        id,
        text,
        parent_id,
        CAST(NULL as VARCHAR(500)) as path
        0 as depth
    FROM new_components_table
    WHERE parent_id IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        nct.id,
        nct.text,
        nct.parent_id,
        cte.path + '>' + nct.text as path,
        cte.depth + 1 as depth
    FROM
        recursiveCTE cte
        INNER JOIN new_components_table nct ON
            cte.id = nct.parent_id
)
SELECT id,text,parent_id, path, depth FROM recursiveCTE
```

Comment: The first two queries are pretty darned close; though...I see children.id > parents.id yet, no reference to the alias [parents]...is this an alias of a join?

Comment: My apologies. that was left over garbage from a first attempt using a LEFT OUTER JOIN. I will remove.

Comment: Also, I just realized with that second query using the number of space characters to determine the parent, if the parent's text has a space in it besides the leading space, then that query will need some extra work to account for those. Like if the parent's text is "   Parent Text" then that space between the two letters will be counted as well and screw it all up. But we are already walking a pretty thin wire here using leading spaces and the order of records to determine the relationships in the hierarchy, so it could get ugly if there are other requirements like that.

Comment: I hear ya; I am only focusing on the initial query...while it does traverse the tree...parent_id is currently only ever 1;  however if I use the < for the children.id > components.Id of course I get the child of the parent.  I cannot yet resolve to the actual parent id....if I can do that; then you got the answer ...

Comment: Got it; change the query to ORDER BY id DESC and voila; parents...and then filter to ischild=1